# Tensor product with $\mathbb{R}$ of an even unimodular lattice

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-forms, lattices

Let $\Lambda$ be an unimodular even lattice of signature $(m,n)$.
By a classifying theorem by Milnor, $\Lambda$ must be of the form $U^k\oplus E_8(\pm 1)^l$, where $U$ is the hyperbolic plane.

Now consider $\Lambda_{\mathbb{R}}:=\Lambda\otimes \mathbb{R}$. I know that $\Lambda_\mathbb{R}$ is isometric to $\mathbb{R}^{m+n}$ with the quadratic diagonal form of signature $(m,n)$.

My question is: suppose we want to visualise $\Lambda$ as a subset of $\mathbb{R}^{m+n}$ through the given isometry, is it legitimate to see it as $\mathbb{Z}^{m+n}$?

Of course my question concerns only the point of view of sets and "how the points are placed", because of course the quadratic form restricted to $\Lambda$ must be even.

Comment: Also posted at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/420442/tensor-product-with-mathbbr-of-an-even-unimodular-lattice

Comment: Can you make your question more mathematically precise?